# Why are there two Android SDK Platforms to choose?

Tags: android, sdk

When I open my Android SDK-Manager I see the option Android SDK Platform 29 twice for Android 10.0

[image]

What is the difference and what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are of different versions. Go with the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Look at version column. Their versions are different 3 and 1 use newer one